# Запрет просмотра папки только через браузер

Tags: веб-программирование, .htaccess

Мне надо запретить доступ к файлам для просмотра через браузер. Для этого создал файл `.htaccess` и написал там такое

```
Deny from all
```

Все хорошо, файлы не показываются. Но мне надо, что бы плеер на сайте имел доступ к файлам (это видеофайлы), потому что сейчас не работает

Comment: Потому что плеер это тот же самый браузере!

Comment: а как можно сделать, что бы плеер показывал, а через браузер нет?

Comment: Говоря о плеере вы говорите об отдельной программе?

Comment: скорее скрипт, а точнее uppod

Comment: Посмотрите эту статью на вики https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, нужно написать скрипт, который будет возвращать бинарный код ролика зашифрованный base64 или другим алгоритмом шифрования, и сделать его индексным в пределах того каталога, доступ к которому через браузер требуется заблокировать.

Также, модифицировать код проигрывателя, чтобы он расшифровывал полученный код и отображал его как видеозапись.

Это является самым простым примером DRM.

Также, как сказал Visman, рекомендую вам просмотреть статью о DRM в Википедии.
Удачи!